# wpf databinding to the object

Tags: wpf, object, data-binding

For example i got a class person:

```
class Person {
     string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my mainWindow of my wpf application i got a ObservableCollection with this class and i want to display this in a table.
I get it working to display the members(only Name in this case) in a table, but for some reasons i got a button in the table. In this button i use the 'command' property in the xaml file to bind an ICommand to it.

Thats what i got working sofar but how can i send the object 'Person' itself as parameter to the command? i used the commandparameter in the xaml succesfully for string / int but how can i send the object i'm displaying in the row?

Thnx!

Comment: You should be able to just pass the object itself as the `CommandParameter` using `CommandParameter="{Binding }"`

Comment: thnx go try it ;)
Its working! you are great :D

Comment: it's important you understand why that worked ... to understand binding , 
the DataContext of that particular Row is a Person so {Binding} is Short For {Binding Path=DataContext}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=}" CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=ObjectToSendWithCommand" />`
```

Sounds like you're not binding the object correctly in the CommandParameter value. I needs to be a public property either in the codebehind or in your ViewModel (if you're using MVVM) and if this value changes it will need to utilize the PropertyChanged event.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same thing, but I did not find any way for create a `Binding` into another binding. How I solve this:

I make a `SelectedItem` property in the same place where the `ICommand` is, then I bind the selected items of the collection to my `SelectedItem` property, `mode=TwoWay`. In this way, I always have in my `SelectedItem` property the collection's selected item, and in the `ICommand` I can access it.

Hope this help you to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You Xaml File Look like

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MultipleCopyList, Mode=TwoWay}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"  /> 
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Your Trigger Look like

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">


<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseClickCommand,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter ="{Binding}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And Your ViewModel Look Like

```
private RelayCommand<StateForm> _MouseClickCommand;
    public RelayCommand<StateForm> MouseClickCommand
    {
        get {
            if (_MouseClickCommand == null)
            {
                _MouseClickCommand = new RelayCommand<StateForm>(e => MouseClick(e));
            }
            return _MouseClickCommand; }
        set
        {
            _MouseClickCommand = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MouseClickCommand");
        }
    }
  private void MouseClick(StateForm e)
    {
   Your Code goes Here
       }
```